# Find Index of First Parent with Class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I've got a jQuery Accordion where every panel is represented by a `<div>` element with the class `.ui-accordion-content`.  Every panel has a form inside of it.  On each form's submit event, I would like to open up the next panel.

I would like to travel up the DOM tree from the form, find the first `div` with the class `.ui-accordion-content`, and return its index on the page, so I know which form was "submitted" and which panel to open up next.

The here's the function I wrote:

```
$("form").each(function () {
    $(this).submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent from submitting the form.
        $("#accordion").accordion({ active: $(this).closest(".ui-accordion-content").index() });
        return false;
    });
});
```

It doesn't return the correct indices.  What's going wrong?

EDIT: Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="Accordion">

    <h3 class="ui-accordion-header"></h3>
    <div class="ui-accordion-content FormOne">
        <form>
        </form>
    </div>

    <h3 class="ui-accordion-header"></h3>
    <div class="ui-accordion-content FormTwo">
        <form>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean, index on the page?

Comment: You should provide relevant HTML in question.

Comment: Can you try: `active: $(this).closest(".ui-accordion-content").index(".ui-accordion-content") + 1` ?!

Comment: @A. Wolff That worked!  If your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as the answer.  Why does *this* work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter out selection regarding `.ui-accordion-content` elements only. So pass selector param of jQuery's [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method and add 1 to get the next one:

`active: $(this).closest(".ui-accordion-content").index(".ui-accordion-content") + 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use parents and find the first .ui-accordion-content.

```
$("form").each(function () {
  var self = $(this);
  self.submit(function (e) {
    var _index = self.parents('.ui-accordion-content:first').index();
    e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent from submitting the form.
    $("#accordion").accordion({ active: _index });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) selector to traverse up the tree and find the matching parent.

`$(this).parents(".ui-accordion-content").index()`

Comment: What's wrong with using `.closest(".ui-accordion-content")`?